# How to send excel file which is generated using jxl.jar from server machine to client

Tags: java, struts2, jxl

I am using struts to develop my web application. I wrote a method which generates excel file and saves it based on the data model I pass.. Works great on my local machine since tomcat is present locally.. But now I've moved my application to a central server.. Now if I use the method it stores generates the excel file in the server not in the client machine which are hitting the server.. I need to pass it from server to client through http.. How do I do that?

```
public static void populateExcelDoc(List<ColumnList> listOfColumns,RowList rowlist,String filename)
{
    try
    {
        WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
        ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename+".xls"), ws);
        WritableSheet s = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 1);
        writeDataSheetifx1(s,listOfColumns,rowlist);
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();

        Process p = 
                  Runtime.getRuntime()
                   .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + filename+".xls");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(WriteException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what my current code looks like.. What change do I need to make? Should I be using HttpServletResponse response?

Comment: The [JExcelAPI FAQ page](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/) actually contains an example of writing Excel files to a servlet response. Look for 'How do I output an Excel file from a Servlet?', within the FAQ.

Comment: I am sorry the question may be lame but can you tell me how to do it in struts? Here we don't pass HttpServlet objects right. and i dnt have doGet method.. Can u change my existing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Struts2 there is `stream` result for sending data to the HttpServletResponse.

In your `struts.xml` configure your action to use `stream` result.

```
<action name="exceldoc" method="populateExcelDoc" class="ExcelDocAction">
  <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=excel.xls</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

And inside your action create `private InputStream inputStream;` with getters/setters and write your file to it inside your method.

Comment: You can also parameterize the file name with a `String fileName` with its getter in the Action, and the following line: `<param name="contentDisposition">attachment; filename="${fileName}.xls"</param>`

Comment: Sorry. Its not helping.. I am calling populateExcelDoc() from a method of a different class which is mapped at struts.xml.. Can you please modify my code and explain? I need to access HttpResponse object.. If u search for "How do I output an Excel file from a Servlet?" in this link http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/ it gets response object from doGet() method.. Here I can't have doGet() because I am calling static method populateExcelDoc() from other place.. Don't know how to move forward..

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, two of them are:

1) Save the file in a place where a client browser can access it

To do this, you will have to find out a decent directory to store the file. When you are using a Servlet, you can create an absolute file systems path from a relative URL path using this method:

```
String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/MyFile.xls");
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filePath), ws);
...
```

Then users can access it from the browser using a URL like: `http://host:port/AppName/MyFile.xls`

You could also modify the response header, so that the browser has to read the file:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=/MyFile.xls");
```

Disadvantage of this method is that the file will be accessible for everybody and that you probably will have to think about generating unique file names, if there are multiple users generating the file again and again. Then you will also have to implement a delete routine for old files.

2) Send the file directly from the servlet to the browser.

If the response of your Servlet request can be the created Excel file, this is probably the best way.

Set the response header accordingly to the file type and size:

```
response.setContentLength(length);
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.getOutputStream().write(...);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

After writing the data, the file can be deleted from the servers file system.

Comment: I had tried your second approach actually.. But plz tell me how to have the response object instatantiated? Because I call populateExcelDoc() method from other class.. Plz modify my code and let me know..

Comment: The response object is created by the web server for you and passed to the servlet doGet() and doPost() methods. You have to pass it from the doGet() or doPost() method of your servlet to your class, or return the document a a result to the doPost()/doGet() method and write it from there.

Comment: Okay I did add  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{} method but how will I pass parameters to populateExelDoc(parameters) method? Because parameters are coming from a method of other class.. Parameters which I pass has to first go through doGet and then populateExcelDoc(). How to do that?

Comment: without knowing the rest of your code, it is difficult to tell you how to do it exactly. How does this "other class" look and how is called?